# Problemas com HTTP Response

Tags: java, http

Estou estudando o uso de sockets e multithreading para montar um servidor HTTP em Java, porém estou passando por algumas complicações. Quando rodo o código do servidor, ele abre corretamente no Internet Explorer, porém no Google Chrome ele nem chega a exibir o Index do server (o navegador indica um erro de **HTTP RESPONSE**).

Além disso, há um outro problema: mesmo com o server rodando no Internet Explorer, requisições para imagens e arquivos PDF não funcionam. Pensei ser algo relacionado ao Content Type, entretanto eu lido com isso no código, e ainda sim qualquer imagem ou arquivo PDF é exibido de maneira totalmente desconfigurada no browser.

Estou estudando por **[este](https://github.com/dasanjos/java-WebServer)** código, porém usando um `HashMap` para salvar os dados do cabeçalho e outras modificações.

Como o programa possui várias classes, decidi colocá-las juntas **[neste link](https://codeshare.io/2BgQ9x)** do Codeshare. Segue também o código abaixo:

**Classe `ServidorHTTP`**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

/**
 * Copyright 2011 Dasanjos.com. All rights reserved.

 Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without modification, are
 permitted provided that the following conditions are met:

 1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice, this list of
 conditions and the following disclaimer.

 2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice, this list
 of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation and/or other materials
 provided with the distribution.

 THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY DASANJOS.COM ''AS IS'' AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED
 WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND
 FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL DASANJOS.COM OR
 CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR
 CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR
 SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON
 ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING
 NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF
 ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.

 The views and conclusions contained in the software and documentation are those of the
 authors and should not be interpreted as representing official policies, either expressed
 or implied, of DASANJOS.COM.

 */

public class ServidorHTTP
{

    private static final int porta = 8085;

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException
    {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(porta);
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);
        System.out.println("O servidor está esperando solicitações da porta " + porta + "...");

        while(true) {
            executorService.submit(new Conexao(serverSocket.accept()));
        }
    }

}
```

**Classe `Conexao`**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Conexao implements Runnable {
    private Socket socket;

    public Conexao(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            Requisicao requisicao = new Requisicao(socket.getInputStream());
            Resposta resposta = new Resposta(requisicao);
            resposta.write(socket.getOutputStream());
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Erro na solicitação!");
        }
    }
}
```

**Classe `Requisicao`**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Requisicao {

    private Metodo metodoRequisicao;
    private String recurso;
    private String versaoProtocolo;
    private Map<String, String> cabecalho = new HashMap<>();

    public Requisicao(InputStream dadosCliente) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dadosCliente));
        String dadosRecebidos = bufferedReader.readLine();
        parsearDadosRecebidos(dadosRecebidos);
        dadosRecebidos = bufferedReader.readLine();

        while (!dadosRecebidos.equals("")) {
            parsearCabecalho(dadosRecebidos);
            dadosRecebidos = bufferedReader.readLine();
        }

        cabecalho.forEach((k,v)-> System.out.println(k + v));

    }

    private void parsearDadosRecebidos(String dadosRecebidos) {
        String[] mensagemParseada = dadosRecebidos.split("\\s+");
        metodoRequisicao = Metodo.valueOf(mensagemParseada[0]);
        recurso = mensagemParseada[1];
        versaoProtocolo = mensagemParseada[2];
    }

    private void parsearCabecalho(String dadosRecebidos) {
        String[] chaveValor = dadosRecebidos.split(":");
        cabecalho.put(chaveValor[0] + ":", chaveValor[1]);
    }

    public Map<String, String> getCabecalho() {
        return cabecalho;
    }

    public Metodo getMetodoRequisicao() {
        return metodoRequisicao;
    }

    public String getRecurso() {
        return recurso;
    }

    public String getVersaoProtocolo() {
        return versaoProtocolo;
    }
}
```

**Classe `Resposta`**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Resposta {

    private Map<String, String> cabecalhoResposta = new HashMap<>();
    private String versaoProtocolo = "HTTP/1.1";
    private byte[] corpoMensagem;

    public Resposta(Requisicao requisicao) throws IOException {
        switch (requisicao.getMetodoRequisicao()) {
            case GET:
                try {
                    formarCabecalho(StatusCode.statusCode_200);
                    File arquivo = new File("." + requisicao.getRecurso());
                    if (arquivo.isDirectory()) {
                        cabecalhoResposta.put("Content-Type: ", ExtensaoRecurso.HTML.getExtensaoRecurso());
                        StringBuilder raizServidor = new StringBuilder("<html><head><title>Index of ");
                        raizServidor.append(requisicao.getRecurso());
                        raizServidor.append("</title></head><body><h1>Index of ");
                        raizServidor.append(requisicao.getRecurso());
                        raizServidor.append("</h1><hr><pre>");

                        File[] arquivos = arquivo.listFiles();
                        for (File subfile : arquivos) {
                            raizServidor.append(" <a href=\"" + subfile.getPath() + "\">" + subfile.getPath() + "</a>\n");
                        }
                        raizServidor.append("<hr></pre></body></html>");
                        formarResposta(raizServidor.toString());
                    } else if (arquivo.exists()) {
                        definirTipoConteudo(requisicao.getRecurso(), cabecalhoResposta);
                        formarResposta(getBytes(arquivo));
                    } else {
                        formarCabecalho(StatusCode.statusCode_404);
                        formarResposta(StatusCode.statusCode_404.getDescricaoMensagem());
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    formarCabecalho(StatusCode.statusCode_400);
                    formarResposta(StatusCode.statusCode_400.getDescricaoMensagem());
                }
                break;
            case POST:
                formarCabecalho(StatusCode.statusCode_201);
                break;
            default:
                formarCabecalho(StatusCode.statusCode_500);
                formarResposta(StatusCode.statusCode_500.getDescricaoMensagem());
        }
    }

    private void formarResposta(String resposta) {
        corpoMensagem = resposta.getBytes();
    }

    private void formarResposta(byte[] resposta) {
        corpoMensagem = resposta;
    }

    private void formarCabecalho(StatusCode statusCode) {
        cabecalhoResposta.put(versaoProtocolo + " ", statusCode.getDescricaoMensagem());
        cabecalhoResposta.put("Connection: ", "close");
        cabecalhoResposta.put("Server: ", "ServidorHTTP");
    }

    private void definirTipoConteudo(String recurso, Map<String, String> cabecalhoResposta) {
        try {
            String extensaoArquivo = recurso.substring(recurso.indexOf(".") + 1);
            cabecalhoResposta.put("Content-Type: ", ExtensaoRecurso.valueOf(extensaoArquivo.toUpperCase()).getExtensaoRecurso());
            System.out.println(cabecalhoResposta);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Conteúdo do arquivo não aceito pelo servidor!");
        }
    }

    private byte[] getBytes(File file) throws IOException {
        int length = (int) file.length();
        byte[] array = new byte[length];
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
        int offset = 0;
        while (offset < length) {
            int count = in.read(array, offset, (length - offset));
            offset += count;
        }
        in.close();
        return array;
    }

    public void write(OutputStream os) throws IOException {
        DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(os);

        for(Map.Entry<String,String> pair : cabecalhoResposta.entrySet()) {
            String chaveValor = pair.getKey() + pair.getValue();
            output.writeBytes(chaveValor + "\r\n");
            System.out.println(chaveValor);
        }

        output.writeBytes("\r\n");

        if (corpoMensagem != null) {
            output.write(corpoMensagem);
        }
        output.writeBytes("\r\n");
        output.flush();
    }

}
```

**Enum `StatusCode`**

```
public enum StatusCode {
    statusCode_200("200 OK"),
    statusCode_201("201 Created"),
    statusCode_301("301 Moved Permanently"),
    statusCode_400("400 Bad Request"),
    statusCode_401("401 Unauthorized"),
    statusCode_404("404 Not Found"),
    statusCode_500("500 Internal Server Error");

    private String descricaoMensagem;

    StatusCode(String descricaoMensagem) {
        this.descricaoMensagem = descricaoMensagem;
    }

    public String getDescricaoMensagem() {
        return descricaoMensagem;
    }
}
```

**Enum `Metodo`**

```
public enum Metodo {
    GET("GET"),
    POST("POST");

    private String nomeMetodo;

    Metodo(String nomeMetodo) {
        this.nomeMetodo = nomeMetodo;
    }

    public void setNomeMetodo(String nomeMetodo) {
        this.nomeMetodo = nomeMetodo;
    }

    public String getNomeMetodo() {
        return nomeMetodo;
    }
}
```

**Enum `ExtensaoRecurso`**

```
public enum ExtensaoRecurso {
    PNG("image/png"),
    JPG("image/jpeg"),
    JPEG("image/jpeg"),
    TXT("text/plain"),
    HTML("text/html"),
    CSS("text/css"),
    GIF("image/gif"),
    PDF("application/pdf"),
    XML("text/xml");

    private String extensaoRecurso;

    ExtensaoRecurso(String extensaoRecurso) {
        this.extensaoRecurso = extensaoRecurso;
    }

    public String getExtensaoRecurso() {
        return extensaoRecurso;
    }
}
```